# clean way to download multiple time series from Bloomberg in R

Tags: r, bloomberg, blpapi

i am trying to download some time series data about euro swaps (EUSA10 Currency for example) in R using the blpapi but i am encountering the following problems:

1. if i try to download for example 2y, 5y, 10y and 30y swap rates using the `include.non.trading.days=FALSE` option , the resulting time series are for some reason of different length and i receive a message error about it. If, on the other hand i set the non trading day option to true i have similar length time series that can then be cleaned up using the na.omit() function

2. the format in which the data is downloaded is messy...i would like to have a data frame in which the first column is the date, second column is the first security, third column is second security and so forth. Instead what i get is `[date][security][date][security2]......[date][securityN]`. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Below a quick few lines i wrote as an example

```r
# Load package
library(Rblpapi)
# Connect to Bloomberg
blpConnect()
# Declaring securities
sec<-c("eusa2 curncy", "eusa5 curncy", "eusa10 curncy")
# Declaring field to be dowloaded
flds<-"PX_LAST" 

data<-as.data.frame(bdh(sec,flds,start.date=as.Date("2019-08-18"),end.date=as.Date("2020-08-18"), include.non.trading.days=TRUE"))
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

It's states in the Rblapi [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rblpapi/Rblpapi.pdf) that the `Rblapi::bdh` returns

> A list with as a many entries as there are entries in securities; each list contains a data.frame with
> one row per observations and as many columns as entries in fields. If the list is of length one, it
> is collapsed into a single data frame. Note that the order of securities returned is determined by the
> backend and may be different from the order of securities in the securities field.

So I'd suggest you `rbind` the data then reshape it in order to have the result you want. a fast way to do it is use the `data.table::rbindlist` function it takes a list as input and returns a `data.table` containing all entries and if `idcol=TRUE` then it'll append a `.id` column showing where the data.frame came from. Also this method will work even if you have different number of rows in the `data.frame`s resulting from the `Rblapi::bdh` call.

```r
# Declaring field to be dowloaded
flds<-"PX_LAST" 

# LOADING THE DATA FROM THE API
l <- bdh(sec,flds,start.date=as.Date("2019-08-18"),end.date=as.Date("2020-08-18"), include.non.trading.days=TRUE)

# the names of the securities columns as returned by the api
securities <- paste0("eusa", c(2,5,10,15,30), ".curncy.",flds)

# row binding the resulting list
dt <- data.table::rbindlist(l, idcol=T, use.names=FALSE) 
# idcol=T appends an id column (.id) to the resulting data.table
# use.names=F because the columns of the data.frames are different

# remaking the .id column so it reflects the name of the column that it already had
dt[, .id:= securities[.id] ]


# making a wider data.table
data.table::dcast(dt, eusa2.curncy.date ~ .id, value.var=securities[1]) 
# eusa2.curncy.date is the column that defines a group of observation
# .id the name of the columns
# securities[1] or eusa2.curncy.PX_LAST is the column that contains the values
```

---

## data used

As I don't have access to a bloomberg api endpoint I created this mock data which resemble the output of `dbh`

```r
col.names <- paste0("eusa", rep(c(2,5,10,15,30),each=2), ".curncy.", rep(c(flds,"date"), 5))
l<-rep(list(data.frame(rnorm(200), 1:200)), 5)

for (i in 1:length(l)) colnames(l[[i]]) <- col.names[(2*i-1):(2*i)]
```

Comment: hello and thanks for your suggestion. tho i've tried and it doesnt seem to be working, i suppose there is something peculiar in the way data are dowlonaded from blp that doesnst allow your command to work properly (i've tried with the mock data and it gets pretty close to what i'm looking for)

Comment: i've figured it out.. can t remember the error now but i've found a nice workaround.
basically ive used the bdh command inside an "as.data.frame" call. After i got the data i just wrote few lines to rename the columns so they can be arranged and interpreted easily. I'm sure there could have been a more elegant way (i litteraly just started in R last month without any previous experience) but it gets the work done, i will improve it as i learn more. Thanks a lot for your help it pointed me in the right direction! thanks again

Comment: if you're new to `R` than the error is probably that the `data.table` package is not installed, run `install.packages("data.table")`

Comment: i honestly can not remember the error, tho now it works . Are you familiar with the getBars function in the blpapi package too? today i moved to intraday data and struggling again

Comment: @zwap I advise you to open a new question to show the error in detail. I'd be happy to help.